# What does the word "scale" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Here is a sentence from a platform game app:

> In the game some of the jumps will take several re-runs to **scale**.

The player has to jump and safely land without tumbling into pits.

I know the [lexical meanings](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/scale_2) of the word **scale**, but none of them seems to fit here.

Comment: There's also the compound adjective "[to scale](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/to-scale)" meaning "having the same relative proportions," but that doesn't seem to fit (no pun intended) and I agree that none of the meanings of "scale" as a verb seem to fit the sentence either. Maybe this is a typo, or an awkward word choice by a non-native speaker.

Comment: @TypeIA: Not so. *Any* decent dictionary will have the relevant definition, as provided by chatnoir below. I'm half-inclined to closevote on the grounds that this is a straightforward "word meaning" question that could easily be resolved by using online resources (dictionaries).

Comment: @FumbleFingers However, scale is not usually used for the act of jumping, only climbing. So the question appears relevant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that a good dictionary - including the one linked by the OP - will list the meaning to which you refer. But I don't agree that this meaning fits the sentence provided by the OP (for the reason chatnoir stated).

Comment: @chatnoir: I can't really agree. Here are several written instances of [***scale the potential barrier***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22scale+the+potential+barrier%22) (in the context of quantum "tunneling"), where the specific metaphorical reference is to sub-atomic particles going ***over*** a "high potential" barrier to reach a nearby lower point of equilibrium. Whether they *actually* "jump over" or "tunnel through" is effectively a matter of which macro-scale metaphor you want to apply, but clearly ***scale*** fits with the former perspective perfectly well.

Comment: Interesting. Could “several re-runs to scale” actually mean the jumps will take several attempts to get over and expecting to get over on the first attempt is unrealistic, or, or each jump needs several run ups  to get over, regardless. The meaning is unclearq

Comment: What happens in the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the original writer of the sentence is using **scale** in the following way:

> **Scale** (with object): Climb up or over (something high and steep). – Oxford Dictionaries (link below)

If we replaced *jumps* with *mountains*, the sentence would read perfectly fine:

> In the game some of the mountains will take several re-runs to scale.

But here we have:

> In the game some of the *jumps* will take several re-runs to **scale**.

where instead of mountains we have *jumps* (think *ski-jumps*).

However, it appears that the author may have taken liberties with the word somewhat if the required action was to *jump* towards something (high) rather than to *climb*.

The examples given in the Oxford Dictionaries had to do with:

> **scaling** fences, mountains, slopes, ladders, hills, heights, inclines, roofs, ledges, roofs, walls, stairs and the like.

That is, all the objects required physically *climbing* them rather than jumping.

- Oxford Dictionaries link [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scale#h47233375286660) – scroll down a little and see "Verb" [with object], Definition 1.

Comment: Can you, please, link to scale in Oxford Dictionary?

Comment: Sure, updated with link.